# How to block some keyboard layouts in NSTextField?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there a way to block some keyboard layouts (input sources) in NSTextField.

I need to block all non-romans languages such as Russian, Belorussian, Ukraine and etc or disable all languages and enable only English/Deutsch language.

If it will be not so hard - make some example please.

UPD:

I think i need to use [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/Reference/reference.html)

but how? =)

Answer (score 0):

Checking just the keyboard attached is maybe a bit flakey. With the Option key you can input a lot non-Roman characters from any keyboard, for instance. Not to mention copy and paste.

A better approach would be to make a subclass of `NSFormatter` and implement `isPartialStringValid:proposedSelectedRange:originalString:originalSelectedRange:errorDescription:`

A simple implementation could be something like this:

```
- (BOOL)isPartialStringValid:(NSString **)partialStringPtr proposedSelectedRange:(NSRangePointer)proposedSelRangePtr originalString:(NSString *)origString originalSelectedRange:(NSRange)origSelRange errorDescription:(NSString **)error
{
    NSString *partialString = *partialStringPtr;

    NSCharacterSet *acceptedCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];

    NSCharacterSet *notAcceptedCharacters = [acceptedCharacters invertedSet];


    BOOL needsCheck = YES;
    BOOL didChange = NO;

    do {
        NSRange rng = [partialString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notAcceptedCharacters];

        if ( !NSEqualRanges(rng, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)) ) {

            partialString = [partialString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:rng withString:@""];

            didChange = YES;
        }
        else {
            needsCheck = NO;
        }

    } while (needsCheck);

    if ( didChange ) {

        *partialStringPtr = partialString;
        NSRange newRange = origSelRange;
        newRange.length = 0;
        *proposedSelRangePtr =newRange;

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

When subclassing `NSFormatter` you are also required to implement `stringForObjectValue:` and `getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:`, but since you are inputting a string, they can just pass the input string straight through.